# Deprecated: mysql_escape_string(): This function is deprecated; use mysql_real_escape_string() instead

Tags: php

Necesita Ayuda con esto, por favor gracias

> Deprecated: mysql_escape_string(): This function is deprecated; use
>   mysql_real_escape_string() instead. in
>   C:\wamp64\www\crudmvc\app\Controller.php on line 29

```
protected function getSql($clave){
        if(isset($_POST[$clave]) && !empty($_POST[$clave])){
            $_POST[$clave] = strip_tags($_POST[$clave]);
            if(!get_magic_quotes_gpc())
                $_POST[$clave] = mysql_escape_string($_POST[$clave]);

            return trim($_POST[$clave]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Rak, bienvenido a SOes. Te recuerdo que este es un sitio en español. Te invito a [edit] tu pregunta y traducirla, de lo contrario podria quedar en espera o cerrada.  Para promover la calidad y orden del sitio, con gusto respondere cuando la traduzcas. Saludos!

Comment: Estas recuperando una variable por POST o por parámetro, no entiendo tu código o qué intentas hacer, el error es obvio, la línea mysql_scape_string() ya no es usada, utiliza mysql_real_scape_string()

Comment: Hi.. the official language of the site is spanish. If spanish is your first language, please translate the question.

Comment: @AlbertoSiurob no solemos contestar preguntas (ni comentarlas) que no esten en el idioma oficial del sitio, hasta que las mismas no esten traducidas. Gracias.

Comment: Estas recuperando una variable por POST o por parámetro, no entiendo tu código o qué intentas hacer, el error es obvio, la línea mysql_scape_string() ya no es usada, utiliza mysql_real_scape_string() – Alberto Siurob, lo hice pero tampoco me funciono

Comment: Rak tienes algun otro problema en otra parte de tu codigo? Que version de php estas usando? Te pregunto porque la clase mysql esta [obsoleta desde la version 5.5 de php](http://php.net/manual/es/intro.mysql.php).

Comment: Kenny gracias, estoy con la version 5.6 y vieras que si me di cuenta que esta obsoleta pero cuando quiero cambiarlo igual me da error :-(